# Unable to save calculated attributes to data model in django throwing error 'int' object not callable

Tags: django, python-3.7

```
class Room(models.Model):

a = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(9)],blank=True)
b = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(99999)],blank=True)
c = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999)],blank=True)


@property
def cal_room_rent(self):
    if self.room_type == 'SS' :
        return 14000
    elif self.room_type == 'DS' :
        return 8000
    elif self.room_type == 'TS' :
        return 6000

@property
def cal_security_deposit(self):
    return 3000


@property
def cal_limit(self):
    if self.room_type == 'SS' :
        return 1
    elif self.room_type == 'DS' :
        return 2
    elif self.room_type == 'TS' :
        return 3

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.a=self.cal_limit()
    self.b=self.cal_room_rent()
    self.c=self.security_deposit()
    super(Room, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

OUTPUT:

```
TypeError at /admin/pgmanagement/room/add/

'int' object is not callable

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pgmanagement/room/add/
Django Version:     2.1.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'int' object is not callable

Exception Location:     E:\anil_website\svcomforts_1\pgmanagement\models.py in save, line 93
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because `cal_limit`, `cal_room_rent`, `security_deposit`  returns an int object and you tried to call it.
Try this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.a=self.cal_limit
    self.b=self.cal_room_rent
    self.c=self.security_deposit
    super(Room, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I tried this code it is not throwing any error but unable to save fields b,c.

Comment: i can able to save calculated values to a,c but unable to save b

Comment: check `cal_room_rent` method. Is it fulfill any condition or not. For testing return a value by else statement if no condition fulfill.

Comment: added else condition which returns 1000 but  it returns 0 which is default

Comment: check `@property
    def cal_room_rent(self):
        if self.room_type == 'SS' :
            return 14000
        elif self.room_type == 'DS' :
            return 8000
        elif self.room_type == 'TS' :
            return 6000` this method.

Comment: I corrected the mistake i have done now it is working thanks